# Making a button disappear after clicked in php

Tags: php

my current code is this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="submitbutton" value="Submit" onclick="this.style.display='none';">
    Execute Procedure
</button>
```

I am trying to make the button disappear after it is clicked and that onclick event works except when the page updates with the result the button returns. So that during the loading process the button is gone but as soon as it refreshes it returns. I need to accomplish this either by `html` or `php` and guidance would be awesome.

Comment: the way it behaves is normal. every time you refresh the page the DOM will reload hence whatever you have in your html gets rendered again.

Comment: if you can use javascript, then you can make an ajax request onclick and hide the button. because of the nature of an ajax request, the entire page does not reload so your button will disappear until you refresh the entire page again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect any event in PHP, on a generated HTML page.
Use some Javascript or AJAX to parse those events to a PHP page which will treat data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript, you can do something like this:

In html:

```
<button type="submit" name="showButton" value="Submit">
    Execute Procedure
</button>
```

In javascript:

```
$('button[name=showButton]', 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $button = $(this);
    var url = "your endpoint url";
    $.ajax(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        data: {} // data you want to post,
        success: function(){
            $button.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

The example is using jquery, but you can do this with vanilla javascript as well.